# How to round to 3 decimals?

Tags: android, math, rounding, decimal

I have

```
double a= = 13;
double b = 6;
double c = a/b;
```

I want to make sure it returns in three decimals. I tried

```
Math.round(c); //gives me an error instead.
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to format the output, for example to print it or display it in a textview, use:

```
DecimalFormat threeDecRound = new DecimalFormat();
threeDecRound.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
threeDecRound.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
threeDecRound.format(number)
```